# С чего начать создание нейронных сетей на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Задача следующая:

Есть алгоритм детектирования некоторых объектов, в результате работы мы получаем массив точек на изображении (их координаты и тип объекта).

На основе данных вышеуказанного алгоритма, нейросеть должна совершать действия (т.к. по идее это бот, играющий в одну игру, то выходные данные направления активации одного или двух джойстиков из трёх).

Comment: Советую почитать [Книгу-Тарика Рашида](https://palchevsky.ru/uploads/books/2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Если я начну говорить - "с обучения нейронной сети, фичерс-инжиниринга, оценки точности модели и т.д." эта информация будет корректна, хотя вам вряд-ли полезна.

Поэтому начните с простого, с изучения того, что такое нейронная сеть, как она работает, какого типа бывает и для чего используется. Информации - масса в любом виде. Появятся конкретные вопросы-  задавайте.

А пока вопрос - не о чем, увы.

Comment: Я ,получается, соврал, что совсем новичок, т.к. понимаю как создаются нейронные сети и примерно как это всё работает, тренировал каскадные классификаторы хаара.                              
Погуглю о фичерс-инжиниринге.